# How to obtain a list of all members in a server in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--')
members = []
@client.command(aliases = [memberlist])
async def members(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        members.append(member)
    await ctx.send(members)
```

This code doesn't work as the script prints just a single member. I've also tried using message.guild.members but I ran in to the following error (Python 3.9 btw):

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Is there a way to do this?
Answers appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you call this function from somewhere outside or only with the command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable intents in your code.

Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications

Select your application/bot -> Bot -> Enable server members intent and save it

Then use the following code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()  # Allow the use of custom intents
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--', intents=intents)
members = []

@client.command(aliases = [memberlist])
async def members(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        members.append(member)
    await ctx.send(members)
```

Comment: Hi, This still doesn't work, It only prints out a single member. Are there any other possible solutions?