# im trying to send private message for specific account when someone use command . discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i want to send private message to specific account in my server when someone using the command .
im sharing simple code for my case

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user=319668832333594624
    await ctx.user.send("hello")
```

i got this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'user'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user) to get the user object. Then the [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.User) object can use [`.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.User.send)

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx):
    user = client.get_user(319668832333594624)
    await user.send("hello")
```

Comment: i checked now ,, and i got this error  `    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'  `

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794286/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-server-in-discord-py/66795149?noredirect=1#comment118101582_66795149 @EmamOmar

Comment: hello , when i run my script from my vps its shows same error !! ? when i run same script on my pc ,, its work .. :( . any help ?

Comment: @EmamOmar that would be a separate question to post